# Doubt in tensors and underlying linear transformation.

Tags: tensors, differential-forms

Let $T:V \mapsto W$ be a linear transformation. We define the dual transformation

$$T^*:\mathcal{L}^k(W) \mapsto \mathcal{L}^k(V)$$
(which goes in the opposite direction) as follows:

If $f$ is in $\mathcal{L}^k(W)$, and if $v_1, ..., v_k$ are vectors in $V$ then

$$(T^*f)(v_1,...,v_k) = (f(T(v_1)),...,f(T(v_k))$$

This is a section from Munkres-Analysis on Manifolds (Differential forms pg-$224$).

This seems meaningless to me and unnecessary to me.Can someone explain to me what exactly is the use of this definition or what exactly is this trying to explain?

Comment: We are trying to deal in an abstract way with the relation between matrices and their transposes: $(A+B)^t=A^t+B^t, (cA)^t=cA^t, (AB)^t=B^tA^t$.

Comment: It is not really clear .Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @ancientmathematician This is something I am also stuck with. What does tensor represent as a physical object. Munkres defines it in a linear algebraic way which does not clear the intuition behind the definition - is it the generalization of inner product when the domain is of the form $V \times ... \times V$?

Comment: Apologies, I know nothing of Physics. I think elementary courses in Linear Algebra usually deal with dual spaces and dual maps - I know mine did. But I don't have enough time to provide the couple of lectures it takes...

Comment: I am not familiar with the book you are quoting and the notation seems a bit odd to me. But this looks like some version of definition of a pullback: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry) It does what it says: it pulls back the action of $f$ from $W$ to $V$ via the linear map $T$. This has many applications, e.g., in general relativity.